# How to count the number of rows in a flow in Talend?

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I am trying to get the number of rows in a flow in Talend. I have a subjob that looks like this: [image]
How can I get the number of rows from this flow (where the red arrow is) and write that value to another document or store it in a variable. I know I can use a variable like this in the tMap:

[image: tMap]

But that still doesn't help me, because I just need the total number of rows. How can I do this in Talend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talend output components have a global variable called NB_LINE which you can use to get the number of rows written to the component's file or table.
In your case you can use tFileOutputExcel's variable:
(Integer)globalMap.get("tFileOutputExcel_1_NB_LINE")
Note that this is an "after" variable which is available after the file has been written, so you can get it using an OnComponentOk or OnSubjobOk.